# How to load the contents of a file and insert a variable in it using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm adding some html to a div using the following jQuery method:

```
$('#pageTabContent').append($('\
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="'+ticketId+'">\
                        And a whole lot more html here..
                    </div>'));
```

This works fine, but because I've got way too much html in my javascript I want to move that to a separate file. The problem is that I also need to insert the `ticketId` in the html. Is there a way using Javascript/jQuery to load the html from a separate file, but still insert the `ticketId` in it?

[EDIT] Please note that the ticketId is different for every time this piece of code is used. I will be used multiple times within one page load, so I cannot load the ticketId in the html using php. I has to be done client side.

All tips are welcome!

Comment: You could think over a template engine like [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) or [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js).

Comment: Functions accept parameters.

Answer (score 2):

For that *specific* example, it's pretty straightforward:

```
$.get("/path/to/file.html", function(html) {
    var newStuff = $(html);
    newStuff.find("div.tab-pane:first").attr("id", ticketId);
    newStuff.appendTo("#pageTabContent");
});
```

You can generalize that a bit, the basic concept is: 1. Load the HTML, 2. Use jQuery to create DOM elements from it, 3. Use jQuery to find the element in question and modify it, 4. Add to the element.

Another approach is to use some form of templating, either a templating plugin or just DIY:

```
$.get("/path/to/file.html", function(html) {
    html = html.replace("{{ticketId}}", ticketId);
    $("#pageTabContent").append(html);
});
```

Again, there are plugins and templating systems to do that for you, which would offer various features over doing your own.

Answer (score 0):

I generally recommend avoiding dynamic html generation in javascript.
There are several good template based frameworks out there. One I like to use in KnockoutJS http://knockoutjs.com/

Another benefit of this approach is change tracking between your model and your html elements.